# Selenium Webdriver : Reusable xml parsing class method is not working due to return type unknown

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

### My objective is to Create Reusable xml parsing class concerning that return type could be array or arraylist

## My code is working but I wanted reusablity I am unable to create reusable class/method due to return type which could array or arraylist is not working.**

1) I have created a xml file as follows:

```
 <SearchStrings>
    <Search id="1111" type="high">
        <Questions>What is software Testing?</Questions>
        <Tips>How to connect database with eclipse ?</Tips>
        <Multiple>Who was the first prime minister of India? </Multiple>
        <Persons>Who is Dr.APJ Abdul Kalam </Persons>
    </Search>
   <Search id="2222" type="low">
        <Questions>What is Automation Testing?</Questions>
        <Tips>How to use selenium webdriver </Tips>
        <Multiple>Who was the fourth prime minister of India? </Multiple>
        <Persons>Who is Superman? </Persons>
    </Search>    
    <Search id="3333" type="medium">
        <Questions>What is Selenium ide  Testing?</Questions>
        <Tips>How to use selenium webdriver with eclipse  ? </Tips>
        <Multiple>Who was the ninth prime minister of India? </Multiple>
        <Persons>Who is Spiderman? </Persons>
    </Search>  
     <Search id="4444" type="optional">
        <Questions>What is database Testing?</Questions>
        <Tips>How to use Class in java ? </Tips>
        <Multiple>Who was the eight prime minister of India? </Multiple>
        <Persons>Who is motherindia? </Persons>
    </Search>  
</SearchStrings>
```

2) Creating a class which fetch nodes of  tags at once and store all of them in
a String [] SearchString and then use this array to fetch the values and by .sendKeys(value) attribute search them at google.

**Simplified:**

**1) Store elements tag element in an reusable datatype my knowledge is limited so using string array.
2) Fetch string array elements and search them using the .sendkeys(element) at google.**

my code is as below:

```
 package searchexperiment;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

    public class Experiment implements Paths
    {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    static Document document;
    static DocumentBuilder db;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] SearchStrings;
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

        //loading xml as test data

        WebElement googlebox=driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq"));
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(test_xml));

            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

            XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            System.out.println("*************************");
            String expression="/SearchStrings/Search/Questions";
            System.out.println("This is ordered expression \n"+expression);
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for(int i=0;i< nodeList.getLength();i++)
            {
                 // Node nNode = emailNodeElementList.item(j);
                //  Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Taking the loop value");
// below push is not working.
                Object array = push(SearchStrings[i],nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                  String text=nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();  
                  googlebox.clear();
                  googlebox.sendKeys(text);
                  System.out.println("Closing the loop value");

            }
```

I am using the string array in order to make xml parsing class reusable.
I have used an interface to get file name

```
public interface Paths {
String test_xml="XML/Searchtext.xml";
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: [Siking] My question is how to create reusable xml file parsing class.

Comment: I have solved by reference of [http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/arrays-java-basics/java-string-array-example/] WHAT I DID I JUST CREATE String[] SearchElements=new String[4]; AND RETURN SearchElements and then used the following String [] namelist=DocBuilderClass.username();
 for(int i=0;i<namelist.length;i++)
 {
  
  String abc=namelist[i];
  
  googlebox.sendKeys(abc);
  googlebox.clear();
  googlebox.sendKeys(namelist[i]);
  
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reusable method along with class was :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import searchexperiment.Paths;
public class DocBuilderClass implements Paths
{

public static String[] username() 
{
    String[] SearchElements=new String[4];
    try
    {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(test_xml));

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        System.out.println("*************************");
        String expression="/SearchStrings/Search/Tips";
        System.out.println("This is ordered expression \n"+expression);
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        //int size=
        for(int i=0;i< nodeList.getLength();i++)
        {
             // Node nNode = emailNodeElementList.item(j);
            //  Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            System.out.println("Taking the loop value");
            //Object array = push(SearchStrings[i],nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
              String text=nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();  
              //googlebox.clear();
             // googlebox.sendKeys(text);
              SearchElements[i]=text;
              System.out.println("Closing the loop value");

        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    System.out.println("This is a exception" + ex);
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    return SearchElements;

}   
}
```

and then way to call the class was as follows:

```
String [] namelist=DocBuilderClass.username();
    for(int i=0;i<namelist.length;i++)
    {

        String abc=namelist[i];

        googlebox.sendKeys(abc);
        googlebox.clear();
        googlebox.sendKeys(namelist[i]);


    }
```

References were [Reference Link String[] array](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/arrays-java-basics/java-string-array-example/)

[Reference Link XML Parsing](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/)

All I learn that Your basics should be strong to solve a strong and complex problems.